# Use of "it's or their"

Tags: pronouns

Need this sentence to be clarified:

- Operation and Maintenance of Boiler and Turbine, and it's/ their accessories.

Should I use "it's or their"?

Comment: I would just write "Operation and Maintenance of Boiler and Turbine and accessories". In context it seems clear what the accessories belong to.

Answer (score 3):

"it's" is not the correct spelling of the possessive determiner "its". Having said that, notice that "boiler" and "turbine" are two different pieces of equipment, each one with its own accessories, so if you want to refer to the accessories **they** are provided with you should say: "... and **their** accessories."